# AttributeError: Roboclaw instance has no attribute '_port'

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, usb, raspbian, pyserial

I really have tried searching through all the forums. It's confusing. The makers of Roboclaw wrote their Python test scripts (and Roboclaw class) with Python 2.7. As of now, it will NOT work with Python 3.

So I'm stuck with that restriction.

When I run the basic script, it complains that `AttributeError: Roboclaw instance has no attribute '_port'`.

Tech support just keeps telling people they need python 2.7.

I've tried `sudo apt-get install python-serial`. No luck. Still same problem.

I tried `sudo apt-get install python3-serial`, just to see if compatible with 2.x. No luck.

What I wanted to do was blow away ALL python and re-install just what I need. But I read (?) that raspbian/debian uses python for package management?

Error is:

> `Traceback (most recent call last): File "roboclaw_simplepwm.py", line
>   14, in rc.ForwardM1(address,32) #1/4 power forward File
>   "/home/devchu/dev/roboclaw_python/roboclaw_python/roboclaw.py", line
>   647, in ForwardM1 return self._write1(address,self.Cmd.M1FORWARD,val)
>   File "/home/devchu/dev/roboclaw_python/roboclaw_python/roboclaw.py",
>   line 311, in _write1 self._sendcommand(address,cmd) File
>   "/home/devchu/dev/roboclaw_python/roboclaw_python/roboclaw.py", line
>   126, in _sendcommand self._port.write(chr(address)) **AttributeError:
>   Roboclaw instance has no attribute '_port'**`

The Roboclaw device **is** seen (`dmesg`). Also I ran their very basic script which just does an `open()` and that script works.

```
dpkg --get-selections|grep python<br/>
dh-python install<br/>
libpython-stdlib:armhf install<br/>
libpython2.7-minimal:armhf install<br/>
libpython2.7-stdlib:armhf install<br/>
libpython3-stdlib:armhf install<br/>
libpython3.5:armhf install<br/>
libpython3.5-minimal:armhf install<br/>
libpython3.5-stdlib:armhf install<br/>
python install<br/>
python-apt-common install<br/>
python-minimal install<br/>
python-serial install<br/>
python2.7 install<br/>
python2.7-minimal install<br/>
python3 install<br/>
python3-apt install<br/>
python3-minimal install<br/>
python3-serial install<br/>
python3.5 install<br/>
python3.5-minimal install<br/>
```

I'm running Raspberry/Raspbian (I believe it's Stretch) from late last year.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo python [your filename]`

eg. `sudo python packet_serial.py`

I was trying to run `packet_serial.py`. Turns out root blocks changes to comports which you set in your file. Hence, you get the error Roboclaw has no attribute "_port". Adding `sudo` worked for me.